# Jquery Validation and asp.net UpdatePanel seem to be posting back twice?

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I currently have a form that has two textboxes and a submit button. I'm using jquery validation on the two textboxes but since I'm using an asp.net UpdatePanel to fire off the data to the server using AJAX, I'm having some troubles with the validation.

What's happening is I've got the validation to work using the following code:

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Register.ascx.cs" Inherits="CapcoControls.Register" %>
<div id="register">    
    <form id="Form1" runat="server">
    <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server"></asp:ScriptManager>
    <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
        <Triggers>
            <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="btnSubmit" EventName="Click" />
        </Triggers>
        <ContentTemplate>
        <asp:Panel id="pnlWrapper" ClientIDMode="Static" runat="server">
            <asp:TextBox ID="txtName" runat="server" MaxLength="200" TabIndex="1" ClientIDMode="Static" title="NAME"></asp:TextBox>
            <asp:TextBox ID="txtEmail" runat="server" MaxLength="200" TabIndex="2" ClientIDMode="Static" title="EMAIL ADDRESS"></asp:TextBox>
            <asp:ImageButton ID="btnSubmit" runat="server" 
                ImageUrl="~/images/btn_submit.png" ClientIDMode="Static" 
                onclick="btnSubmit_Click" TabIndex="3" />
        </asp:Panel>
        </ContentTemplate>        
    </asp:UpdatePanel>
    </form>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance().add_initializeRequest(initializeRequestHandler);

    function initializeRequestHandler(sender, args) {
        if (args.get_postBackElement().id == '<%= btnSubmit.ClientID %>' && $("#Form1").valid() !== true) {
             args.set_cancel(true);
         }
     }

    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#Form1").validate({            
            rules: {
                <%= txtName.UniqueID %>: {
                    required: true,
                    checkDefaultValue: true
                },                
                <%= txtEmail.UniqueID %>: {
                    required: true,
                    email: true,
                    checkDefaultValue: true
                }
            },
            messages: { },
            errorPlacement: function(error, element) { }            
        });        
    });        
</script>
```

The problem is that once the user DOES enter valid data, the server side click event is getting called **twice** but I'm not sure why? Does anyone have any idea?

My gut feeling is that it's something to do with my jquery validate ie. that the button is posting back by default, and then I'm somehow submitting the form again because of the jquery validation.

Does anyone have any idea where I'm going wrong here?

Thanks

Comment: did u get solution of this ???

Comment: It's been a while since I had this problem but I vaguely recall it was because I had duplicate code somewhere that was firing twice. Sorry I can't be of more help but I don't have access to the code anymore..

Comment: I am using it on button click, it is working fine and does not fire back end code if i don't use UpdatePanel. But if i use it with UpdatePanel then it fires backend code also. Can you tell me how to solve this ???

Answer (score 0):

Try putting everything in `pageLoad`
Link: http://encosia.com/document-ready-and-pageload-are-not-the-same/